# Finding homomorphism when kernel is given

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

I want to know if there is any process of determination of onto group homomorphism when its kernel is given. The converse is usually a routine exercise that can be found in any standard textbook of abstract algebra. However, I am unable to make way for the former problem. For example, I want to find an onto group homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}_{3^6}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3^5}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{3}\times \mathbb{Z}_{243}$ such that $\ker(f)=\langle (30,27)\rangle$. But I am not getting any clue how to solve this sum. Can you please guide me?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is a 1-1 correspondence between all surjective homomorphisms $G\to H$ with kernel $N$, and all isomorphisms $G/N\to H$. And so all you have to do is to calculate the quotient, pick an isomorphism and compose it with the quotient map.